# Excel Pivot Table Measure wIth Two Tables for a Weighted Average

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel 365 pivot table that looks like this

```
Header1 Header2 Header3
  3        2       5
  6        7       4
```

I also have a table of weightings

```
Weight1  Weight2 Weight3
  13       5       8
```

How can I create a measure that multiplies each row against the weights for the weighted sum for that row? At the end of the the header table I should see

```
                  Row Weighted Total
                          89
                         145
```

SUMX almost worked, but it did not or could not see the values from the weightings.